# Solve the differential equation $ {dy \over dt} = ry(K-y) $

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation (population growth model)

$$ {dy \over dt} = ry(K-y) \iff {dy} \cdot {1 \over y(K-y) } = r \,dt $$

where $ r $ and $ K $ are both constants greater than zero. I decomposed the fraction and integrated both sides and got

$$ {1 \over K} \ln{y \over |K-y|} = rt+C \iff {y \over |K-y|} = Ce^{rKt} $$

We also know that $ y(t=0)=10^4 $ and $ y(t=1)=2 \cdot 10^4 $. Moreover, as t $ \to \infty  \,y \to 10^5$

Don't really know how to proceed from here.

Comment: In the first line, multiply a minus on both sides so that you have $y-K$ instead of $K-y$ Redo the partial fraction and integration and let C absorb the absolute sign. Then use the initial conditions and other information provided to find the unknowns.

Comment: @Novice I checked the the OP's work myself and he did everything correctly so far...

Comment: It is better to keep $K-y$ since $0<y<K$ (see my answer below). This is in fact an exercise in the calculus book used at our university (Lund University). If the OP is a student here I invite him to also ask questions in swedish at the local forum.maths.lth.se (If it is not OK to announce that here, please tell me and I'll remove this comment.)

Comment: @mickep the minus is for two purposes. One is a trivial one which is regarding the partial fraction. The other one is regarding to have the solution bounded for large t due to negative exponent. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get $K$ out from the differential equation if we also assume that $\frac{dy}{dt}\to 0$ as $t\to+\infty$. Then
$$
0=r 10^5(K-10^5)
$$
which means that $K=10^5$ (since $r\neq 0$). Then, since you divide by $y$ and $K-y$ and you start with $y$ being $10^4$ you know that $0<y<K$ for all values of $t$ (why?). Thus, $|K-y|=K-y$. Your equation becomes
$$
\frac{y}{K-y}=Ce^{Krt}.
$$
Now, let us use the conditions for $t=0$ and $t=1$. You find that:
$$
\frac{10^4}{10^5-10^4}=C\qquad (t=0)
$$
and
$$
\frac{2\cdot 10^4}{10^5-2\cdot 10^4}=Ce^{r10^5}.\qquad (t=1)
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!

Comment: How do you get ${1 \over K} \ln{y \over |K-y|} = rt+C \iff {y \over |K-y|} = Ce^{rKt}$? Is the final right-hand side not $e^{rKt+CK}$?